# How can I get rid of the "Warning: Invalid configuration encountered" in serverless.yml?

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Currently I'm trying to breakdown my serverless service into multiple services to get over the cloudFormation resource limit.

My current project structure is as follows:

```
aws-backend
  functions
    workers
      serverless.yml // workers service
.env.local
.env.dev
serverless.yml // Rest of the functions in here
```

In my workers service, I'm trying to reference the .env.* files in the root folder using variables.

My issue is when i use the following syntax

`${env:SLS_AWS_REGION}`

I get a

```
Error:Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
 - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.region": Value not found at "env" source
```

but when I use the following syntax:
`${../../env:SLS_AWS_REGION}`

It works but I get a warning:

```
Warning: Invalid configuration encountered
  at 'package.individually': must be boolean
  at 'provider.region': must be equal to one of the allowed values [use-east-1, etc...]
```

How can I get rid of this error? Am I even using the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what I had to do was resolve my own env variables manually. I used this [link](https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-example) as a reference and the explanation in the dotenv plugin of [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv-plugin)

TLDR: If you're using a serverless version beyond `serverless>=2.26.0` then you will most likely need to wire up the envs on your own if you want to relocate your env files

Answer (score 0):

as for this error

```
Error:Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
 - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.region": Value not found at "env" source
```

You get this error because the Framework cannot find `SLS_AWS_REGION` environment variable. The `env` variable source doesn't read from `.env` files, but from environment variables from the process.

As for this syntax:

```
${../../env:SLS_AWS_REGION}
```

This does not work because `env` is a correct variable source, not `../../env`.

You have two options here:

1. Ensure that content of the `.env` file(s) is exported so the variables defined in these files are actually exported as environment variables before running `serverless` commands.
2. Set `useDotenv: true` in your `serverless.yml` file so the `.env` files will be loaded automatically with `dotenv`. Please see the docs for reference on how it works: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables

Comment: I already have useDotenv: true in my serverless.yml file and I'm using the   - serverless-dotenv-plugin

Comment: Could you share which command are you running? What version of Serverless Framework do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the plugin documentation](https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin#automatic-env-file-resolution), you should run `sls deploy` with `--stage` or `--env` (deprecated in Serverless >=3.0.0) or `NODE_ENV` corresponding to the .env file name. If you run it without any of those flags, it will default to `development`, and the plugin will look for the plugin will look for files named .env, .env.development, .env.development.local

Note that [Serverless Framework .env files resolution](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables) works differently to the plugin.

> The framework looks for .env and .env.{stage} files in service directory and then tries to load them using dotenv. If .env.{stage} is found, .env will not be loaded. If stage is not explicitly defined, it defaults to dev.

I believe the plugin takes precedence here.